# Case Insensitive String parameter in schema of openApi

Tags: enums, openapi

I have an open API spec with a parameter like this:

```
- name: platform
  in: query
  description: "Platform of the application"
  required: true
  schema:
    type: string
    enum:
      - "desktop"
      - "online"
```

when I get the "platform" parameter from URL , it can be like this :

```
platform=online or 
platform=ONLINE or 
platform=Online or 
platform=onLine  or ... any other format
```

but when I am going to use it , it is only valid if the parameter is all lower case like *"platform=online"*, obviously to match the enum value.

how can I make schema to be the case insensitive and understand all types of passed parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enums are case-sensitive. To have a case-insensitive schema, you can use a regular expression `pattern` instead:

```yaml
- name: platform
  in: query
  description: 'Platform of the application. Possible values: `desktop` or `online` (case-insensitive)'
  required: true
  schema:
    type: string
    pattern: '^[Dd][Ee][Ss][Kk][Tt][Oo][Pp]|[Oo][Nn][Ll][Ii][Nn][Ee]$'
```

Note that `pattern` is the pattern itself and does not support JavaScript regex literal syntax (`/abc/i`), which means you cannot specify [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) like `i` (case insensitive search). As a result you need to specify both uppercase and lowercase letters in the pattern itself.

Alternatively, specify the possible values in the `description` rather than in `pattern`/`enum`, and verify the parameter values on the back end.

Here's the related discussion in the JSON Schema repository (OpenAPI uses JSON Schema to define the data types): [Case Insensitive Enums?](https://github.com/orgs/json-schema-org/discussions/148)

Comment: thanks but is there anyway to keep the enums? and do not make further changes in my code?
can I provide this pattern match for enum values?

Comment: Only if you extend the enum to include all possible spellings: `enum: [online, ONLINE, Online, OnLiNe, ...]`. There's really no elegant way to describe this scenario.