# Openapi specificiation to java REST points with enums always upper case

Tags: java, enums, openapi

I have an openApi spec which includes the following:

```
  MyType:
    type: string
    enum:
      - foo
      - baz
```

which is used as:

```
"/v1/configuration/{configType}":      
  get:
    operationId: GetConf
    parameters:
      - name: configType
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/MyType"
```

Java generates the enum as:

```
public enum ConfigTypePathParamEnum {
  FOO("foo"),
  BAZ("baz")
```

Having written a test for the endpoint, i can only access the foo endpoint as "/v1/configuration/FOO" (which returns an http error code 400). What i want is "/v1/configuration/foo" to work.

This question is similar, but not quite the same:
[Case Insensitive String parameter in schema of openApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772786/case-insensitive-string-parameter-in-schema-of-openapi/60773255)

I am using openapi generator version 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I use spring-boot and that brings Jackson with it.
Jackson has some nice annotations that control serialisation/deserialisation, so all I have to do is add this method to my enum:

```
@JsonValue
public String toJson() {
    return name().toLowerCase().replaceAll("_","-");
}
```

NB: since we use kebab-case rather than SNAKE_CASE, we also switch dashes for undescores.

Comment: Mmhh, my enum is generator by the generator. I am looking for something which will automatically correct the issue during generation. For now what i do is use an ant task to search and replace.